# jCart shopping cart library

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shopping-cart

I use a shopping cart from :

http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/

But after arriving at the checkout position, I want to make changes to the process.

I want to change it is taking the data contents of the basket has been done by the user. In this regard I would like to take :

```
items, names, prices, qtys, itemCount and subtotal
```

I can see the detail order by doing :

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['jcart']);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

How do I extract the data from the jcart session?

I would like to take this data to send details of the data returned via email to cart users who perform transactions

Comment: Can you provide the output of the print_r($_SESSION['jcart']); ??

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
foreach($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {
    $itemID = $item['id']; //gets the item's ID
    $itemName = $item['name']; //gets the item's name
    $itemPrice = $item['price']; // gets the item's price
    $itemQuantity = $item['qty']; // gets number of this product in cart
    $itemTotal = $item['price']*$item['qty']; // total order value of this line item
}
```

It's then a simple case of looping through and calculating the total number of items and shopping cart total value.